# Validation fails for one or more entities when using ASP.NET MVC and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am new to MVC .i am having problem with the validation error as i checked all the database field i did't find any problem there and still i am getting the error that validation failed for one or more entities .I am unable to locate the validation error.

Here is my database schema:

[image]

```
public partial class make
{
    public int make_id { get; set; }
    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string imagePath { get; set; }

    public virtual category category { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model globalEngineProject.make
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Home", "make", FormMethod.Post,
                            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>category</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.category_id, "category_id", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("category_id", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.category_id)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imagePath, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input name="file" type="file" id="file"/>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imagePath)
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

}
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Home([Bind(Include = "make_id,category_id,title")] make make, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/"), fileName);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                    db.makes.Add(make);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                ViewBag.category_id = new SelectList(db.categories, "category_id", "category_name", make.category_id);
                return View(make);

                // return View("Index");
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException )
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(make);
        }
```

Comment: Inspect `ModelState` to determine what validation errors you have. Note also that nowhere are you setting the value of property `imagePath` before you save the model

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Stephen's comment, it looks like you're not setting the value for `imagePath`. To check this you can put the following code in your controller method to find out the details of the validation errors:

```
var modelErrors = new List<ModelError>();

foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
        modelErrors.Add(error);
    }
}
```

This will give you a list of `ModelError` that you can inspect when debugging. This should give you a pointer to which field has an error.

Comment: The `imagePath` property does not have a `[Required]` attribute so that's unlikely to be the problem (unless OP has not shown the correct code)

Comment: You're right, of course. I had made the assumption that because the view includes `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imagePath)` there must be some validation elsewhere for this property. Of course that may not be the case.

Comment: i added the [Required ] attribute but now i am not able to save the data .it is showing the image path filed is required.

Comment: I'm not sure you want `imagePath` to be required on your model because of the way you're setting it in your controller code. You're not passing `imagePath` to the controller as part of the model binding - you're generating it server side

Comment: thanx for the help i was not settting the value for image path field that's why it was showing validation error

Comment: Here are the changes that i made

Comment: 'if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/"), fileName);
                        make.imagePath = path;
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                    }
                    
                    db.makes.Add(make);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }'